# MPI_Reduce will not send the position of minimum from my array

Tags: mpi

Exactly what my question is ! 
**Bellow is my code i dont know why, it transfers the min data but not the position as the manual of MPI_Reduce says!**

`//where b is an array with N data, int 
     //and min and array with 2 data, int 
       MPI_Reduce(b, min, 1, MPI_2INT, MPI_MINLOC,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
       if(rank==0){
       printf("MIN from B table is =%d\n",min[1]);
       printf("Position of minimum =%d\n",min[0]);
}`

Answer (score 1):

`MPI_MINLOC` does not return the location of the minimum, but the value of the second element of the structure where the minimum of the first is found.

Also, if you use `count=1`, only the first pair of `b` will be used.

If you believe you use it correctly, then update your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)